# Error in accept: Bad file descriptor -- mysql error

Tags: server, 16.04, mysql

After working for years on Ubuntu 14.04 (on OpenVZ) without any problem, I installed a new Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS running on OpenVZ.

I set it up as a LEMP stack.

The problem is that after a while (hours), mysqld starts consuming 100% CPU and the error log is filled with strange '`Error in accept: Bad file descriptor`' errors, over and over again, the err file quicly became 4Gb large.

MySql needs to be setup for replication. With replication enabled, the bin.err file is written in the same way.

I just can't figure out what happens and why. The only thing I did out of the ordinary was to set '`mysqld: ALL`' in hosts.deny and '`ALL: LOCAL`' and a specific IP in hosts.allow, to allow the replication.

Any idea about what's happening?

Comment: Same problem here. After a while (more than an hour, apparently) I get the error. I have hosts.deny mysqld: ALL and hosts.allow mysqld: a /24 network and three single IPs. Did you ever resolve the problem in some way?